# R reads blank character differently

Tags: r, string, character, stringr

I've imported some data from a csv file and R seems to recognize the "seemingly" identical characters differently. My codes below suggest that it's because of the blank characters but don't know how I can fix this.

```
print(mydata)
[1] "3COM CORP"
identical("3COM CORP", mydata)
[1] FALSE
"3COM"==str_sub(mydata,1,4)
[1] TRUE
"3COM "==str_sub(mydata,1,5)
[1] FALSE
> " CORP"==str_sub(mydata,5,9)
[1] FALSE
"CORP"==str_sub(mydata,6,9)
[1] TRUE
 " "==str_sub(mydata,5,5)
[1] FALSE

print(str_sub(mydata,5,5))
[1] " "
```

I've just tried replacing it with an actual space blank, with whatever the blank is in mydata and solved it. But still I don't get what's causing this.

```
badspace<-str_sub(mydata,5,5)

str_replace()
mydata2<-str_replace(mydata, badspace, " ")

identical("3COM CORP", mydata2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Please try `utf8ToInt(mydata)` and `utf8ToInt("3COM CORP")` and compare the results.

Comment: @G5W
utf8ToInt(mydata) >[1] NA
utf8ToInt("3COM CORP") > [1] 51 67 79 77 32 67 79 82 80

Comment: Is `mydata` a string?  `class(mydata)`

Comment: > class(mydata)
[1] "character"

Comment: Odd.  It is hard to see how you get NA from utf8ToInt.  What is `str(mydata)`?

Comment: @G5W If this helps:
> utf8ToInt(mydata)
[1] NA
> utf8ToInt(str_sub(mydata,1,9))
[1]  51  67  79  77 160  67  79  82  80

Comment: @G5W
> str(mydata)
 chr "3COM CORP"

Comment: There is your answer.  You _do_ have a different blank in mydata.  Character 160 is a non-breaking space. The regular blank is character 32.

Comment: `gsub("\\s", " ", intToUtf8(c(32,160)))` converts any whitespace (which apparently includes 160) to a single "32" space.

Comment: Exactly how are you "importing" this data?  Are you copying and pasting it from a browser?  non-breaking spaces are common in HTML and represented in HTML by `&nbsp;`   Note that `charToRaw(s)` will display string `s` in hex and will work in some situations where `utf8ToInt` does not.